# Item ID of title ActionBar

Tags: android, menu

look this image:
[image]

When you click on the "Action bar" string my app enter in this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

So also it is an item, the problem is that i don't know which id it has. 
Where can i get the id of this item ?

Comment: @mmlooloo  put that in an answer silly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android.R.id.home

if you have set

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)‌​;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            //here you put your code
            Toast.makeText(this, "You click Action Bar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```